# Mootools event leak

Tags: mootools

The example to demonstrate the issue can be found here:

[link text](http://jsfiddle.net/tptshepo/47J3y/)

The test shows a basic Mootools class that contains an element variable with a click event attached. There’s also a “cleanup” function to remove the event and nullify the element variable.

My problem is that when I loop a thousand times to create the “LeakClass” instance and clean it up, it causes a major memory leak like there’s no tomorrow. I tested this on IE8 and Chrome.

On the other hand what I’ve noticed is that if I comment out the line that adds the “click” event, the code doesn’t leak.

Can somebody please help me structure the class/event in a manner that it doesn’t leak.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you trying to achieve?

`this.element = null;` does not detatch the element from the DOM or destroy it, it simply removes your reference to it. to do so you should use `this.element.destroy();` which calls up internal cleaning functions - first applies a little GC of child nodes, then does `.empty()`, then removes it from the DOM and finally removes it altogether. your code will just create multitudes of elements that will stop being referenced but lack of reference does not mean lack of existence. each element will use up memory on its own, events or not.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. What I'm trying to simulate here is...what happens when i'm running an AJAX application that constantly adds and removes element with events, is the application going to leak after some time?. This is why I'm creating the class instances in a loop to see if the disposing of the element and it's events doesn't leak. As I've stated on my problem above...when i remove the click event line, the code doesn't leak even thou i'm not calling the "this._element.destroy()". My question is...how do i make the "LeakClass" not leak?

Comment: the click event itself is a callback in Element storage. removing the element will remove the callback too. However, this kind of architecture is wrong anyway. you should _NOT_ be adding/removing events all the time dependent on the data that comes in via ajax, its tiresome and _can_ cause leaks or event stacking up over time. you should DELEGATE the click events to a parent delegate instead. here's an example http://www.jsfiddle.net/GZ6K3/ - needs Element.delegate from mootools-more.

Comment: keep in mind the mouseover delegation is dodgy though (in IE) but you can work around that via CSS:hover. the current mootools implementation does not bubble focus/blur/change for input type elements - but there are plugins that do (search for better event delegation sixtyseconds on github if you need them) and this is likely to change for 1.3.1 or 1.3.2 where delegation will move to mootools-core

Comment: I'm familiar with event delegation in Mootools but even with the event delegation i still need to attach an event to a parent element. What happens when i constantly add and remove the parent element. Won't this cause the same leak as well?

Comment: so delegate to an element that you wont remove--it makes the most sense from an architectural standpoint imo. also, mootools does NOT have an issue cleaning up or it would have been all over the net :) you can delegate to document.body even, events bubble fine...

Comment: Your responses are not what i was expecting but you do make a good point. Thank you for your time.